# Why we get error like 'method takes 1 arguments 2 is given ' after removing self keyword?

Tags: python, class, object, self

Why it shows that xyz method takes 1 argument 2 is given while I am passing single argument to the method and also that method has single parameter. It confused me when I set self keyword as a parameter of the method then code runs without error. Please explain this why.

Here are two code snippets

1. With `self`:

```py
class Demo:
    def show(self,x):
        print("hello {0}".format(x))
o2 = Demo()
o2.show("world")

# Output:
# hello world
```

2. Without `self`:

```py
class Demo:
    def show(x):
        print("hello {0}".format(x))
o2 = Demo()
o2.show("world")

# Output:
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
#     o2.show("ksr")
# TypeError: show() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: Class methods implicitly receive the class instance as the `self` parameter. When you call `o2.show(...)`,then `o2` is implicitly passed as the first parameter to the function, with the name `self`. Basically, `o2.show("world")` is the same as `Demo.show(o2, "world")`. Also worth noting - you can change the word `self` to whatever word you like, it's just a convention to use `self`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python is a little bit different to other languages when it comes to class functions.

If you define a variable inside a class, it is a static variable that belongs to the class, as if the class was an object. Because the class *is* an object. It's a python Dict.

When you create an instance of the class, python copies the Dict and gives it a new name.

In order to create instance variables, you need to attach them to the instance Dict and not to the class Dict.

To avoid the confusion between these two Dicts python introduced the "self" keyword. When python calls a function on an instance Dict it passes a copy of the instance Dict to the function as the first parameter.

Thus to change a variable inside a function you would need to do this:

```
class bicycle:
    numwheels = 2
    def __init__(self):
        # This is what python uses as the constructor
        self.numwheels = 3

    def changeInstanceWheels(self, wheelnum):
        self.numwheels = wheelnum
```

```
bike = bicycle()
print(bicycle.numwheels) # prints 2
print(bike.numwheels) # prints 3

bike.changeInstanceWheels(5)

print(bicycle.numwheels) # still prints 2 because this is the static variable
print(bike.numwheels) # prints 5
```

Answer (score 2):

The instance you call the method on is implicitly the first argument (i.e., `self`). So here, the method gets two arguments - `o2` it's called on, and `"ksr"` which is passed to it, and errors out because it expects just one argument.

Answer (score 2):

When you define methods inside a class, you must include a mandatory first argument, e.g. `self` before the `x` argument, like so

```
class Demo:
    def show(self, x):
        print("hello {0}".format(x))
```

`self` is a variable that holds your Demo class instance.

Your method currently just prints out `x`, and it does not use any class variables. You can avoid using `self` by making your method static like so

```
class Demo:
    @staticmethod
    def show(x):
        print("hello {0}".format(x))
```

or by converting it to static later using the `staticmethod` keyword before the method call like so

```
Demo.show = staticmethod(Demo.show)
o2 = Demo()
o2.show("world")
```

The first option is usually preferred.